# Error while executing Google OAuth2 V1 Command line Sample

Tags: java, android, maven, google-oauth

I am completelly new to OAuth2 and I would like to get this example working before I move to integrate OAuth2 with my application. What I have done is the following:

1. cd [someDirectory]
2. hg clone https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/
   google-api-java-client-samples
3. cd google-api-java-client-samples/oauth2-cmdline-ample
4. cp ~/Downloads/client_secrets.json
   src/main/resources/client_secrets.json
5. mvn compile
6. mvn -q exec:java

This is the error I am getting while executing this code:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.services.samples.oauth2.cmdline.OAuth2Sample.authorize(OAuth2Sample.java:81)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.oauth2.cmdline.OAuth2Sample.main(OAuth2Sample.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your classes folder after step #5? The classes folder should have your client_secrets.json. It should not have "Enter Client ID" etc.

Looking at the stack trace, it seems the application is not able to find client_id in the client_secrets.json and hence failing with NPE.

Comment: There is a client_secrets.json , containing {"installed":{"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","client_email":"","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","oob"],"client_x509_cert_url":"","client_id":"76490936470-hjbnfr6l4tu715h1qekdoikjdsgiob66.apps.googleusercontent.com","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"}}

Comment: it is same as downloaded json file

Comment: And just to confirm, it has client id as well? The code where it is failing is 

"if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")"

Comment: If the client_secrets.json that you have in classpath does not have client_id, above error will be thrown.